# How can I keep the same cell reference in if function, until the if function is true/false?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following function in excel:

INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+53)&O1+1)

This function has to be the outcome of an if-statement when the statement is true. I don't want the O1 to change to O2, O3, etc.. when I drag the function down, until the statement is true. From there I want the function to change this cell reference in ascending order. So as long as the if statement is false, the reference needs to be O1.

I know that absolute referencing can be used to keep the same cell-reference ($O$1), but then the cell reference doesn't change when the statement is true either.

My data looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpERn.png)

My complete formula looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRGVc.png)
=IF(P2=INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+51)&O1+1);IF(INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+51)&O2+1)="";INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+53)&O1+1);INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+51)&O2+1));IF(INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+53)&O2+1)="";"";INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+51)&O2+1)))

What I want to do is to fill a column with values of the first column in the data until the cells are empty. Then I want to fill the column with data from the i+2th  column (so from column C I go to column E). In order for this to happen, I want the first cell of (column E in this case) to stay the same, until column C is empty and the column starts taking values from column E.

I hope that this description gives a clear view of what I want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Excel 2013 or later?

Comment: I use Excel 2016

Comment: Can you do something like date some screenshots - showing what you do and don't want and link that back into your question. Hard to visualise this without data...

Comment: I edited my question with two screenshots and the final formula I use. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is to fill a column with values of the first column in the data until the cells are empty. Then I want to fill the column with data from the i+2th column (so from column C I go to column E). In order for this to happen, I want the first cell of (column E in this case) to stay the same, until column C is empty and the column starts taking values from column E.

It's not the same kind of solution, but this might suit your needs better than your original formula:

```
=
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$1,2,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1),ROW($A1)+0),
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($B$1,2,0,COUNTA(B:B)-1,1),ROW($A1)+1-COUNTA(A:A)),
""))
```

If you need it for more than 2 columns, just extend the formula by following this pattern:

```
=
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$1,2,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1),ROW($A1)+0),
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($B$1,2,0,COUNTA(B:B)-1,1),ROW($A1)+1-COUNTA(A:A)),
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($C$1,2,0,COUNTA(C:C)-1,1),ROW($A1)+2-COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(B:B)),
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($D$1,2,0,COUNTA(D:D)-1,1),ROW($A1)+3-COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(B:B)-COUNTA(C:C)),
""))))
```

Sample implementation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAtxW.png

I've made considerations for your extra blank row between the header and the first row of data. For anyone wanting to use this formula without the blank row in their data set simply change the Offset-Row parameter from 2 to 1:

```
=
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1),ROW($A1)+0),
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($B$1,1,0,COUNTA(B:B)-1,1),ROW($A1)+1-COUNTA(A:A)),
""))
```

You can stick the formula anywhere in your worksheet, but don't forget to change the column letters to suit the location of your fields. In your case, probably:

```
=
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($C$1,2,0,COUNTA(C:C)-1,1),ROW($C1)+0),
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($E$1,2,0,COUNTA(E:E)-1,1),ROW($C1)+1-COUNTA(C:C)),
""))
```

Be aware that you need to make sure your columns don't contain rows with blank cells in between names, as this will cause it to skip an equal number of names at the bottom of the column.

**EDIT:**

I just realized your system uses semi-colons ";" to parse Excel formulas (mine uses commas ","). Please take note of that when copying these formulas to your spreadsheets. Here's the formula again but using ";"...

```
=
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($C$1;2;0;COUNTA(C:C)-1;1);ROW($C1)+0);
IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($E$1;2;0;COUNTA(E:E)-1;1);ROW($C1)+1-COUNTA(C:C));
""))
```